# How to remove background form bulk images easily?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, automation, background-removal, image-editing

I have about 7000 images per day to remove background. How can i do it easily using action or something like that? Does anyone know any easy way? I'm looking for macros or something like that automatic system. Is it available? Please help me. Video tutorial would be best.

Best Regards
Raihanul

Comment: In general, you can't. But it largely depends on the nature of the images. For example if they were all shot on "green screen" or similar you may be able to utilize that to make extraction more efficient. You haven't really supplied enough information to answer this effectively.

Answer (score 1):

theres background removal programs like background burner but the only batch one i can think of is zenfotomatic

Comment: I have not tested it but here is the batch option: http://burner.bonanza.com/pro